# Last block of table fill the rest of the row?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to build a HTML calendar for an email. I cannot figure out how to make the last td fill the rest of the row without messing up the width of the other rows. Is there a way to increase the width of just the 4th block of the last row to fill out the empty space?

Here is a fiddle of the below code: https://jsfiddle.net/b11cj5j0/9/

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;">
<tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
     <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    6
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    7
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
     <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    6
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    7
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
     <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    4
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    5
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    6
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    7
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    1
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
     <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:#BB0000; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    January
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="color:#000000; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:48px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:5px; text-align:center;">
                    3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
        This should fill the rest of the last line
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `colspan` attribute can help you to achieve this.

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;">
   <tr>
<!-- ... previous rows and cells ... -->
        <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:5px;">
            This should fill the last line
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

... and to combine cells in the vertical direction, use `rowspan`.

Answer (score 0):

You can like this:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
td:last-child {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td One Two Three</td>
    <td>td Two Three Four</td>
    <td>td Three Four FiveThree Four FiveThree Four FiveThree Four FiveThree Four Five</td>
    <td>td Four Five Six</td>
    <td>&nbsp;Last</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```